# Mezzanine CMS Django contact us form returns POST 500 error

Tags: django, mandrill, mezzanine

I have installed Mezzanine CMS and all is working except when the contact us form is submitted I get POST 500 error and no email is received.

I am using Mandril for sending emails and DJRILL (https://github.com/brack3t/Djrill)

In my settings.py I have:

```
MANDRILL_API_KEY = "<mandrill api key>"
EMAIL_BACKEND = "djrill.mail.backends.djrill.DjrillBackend"
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = "/var/www/xxxx.com/xxx/mail"
SERVER_EMAIL = "x@myemail.com"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "x@myemail.com"
```

Of course I have djrill added to my INSTALLED_APPS too.

I have tried using SMTP settings for Mandrill too and I get the same.

Any suggestions on why I am getting this problem?

This is running on debian 7.4 / nginx / uwsgi setup.

Any questions let me know.

Comment: If you switch to some other email backend, does the behavior change? E.g., try using Django's filebased.EmailBackend (temporarily), and see if the email gets written to the temp file. If it does, you'll need to figure out why your server cannot contact Mandrill's servers. If not, the problem is in your contact form code, not in Djrill/Mandrill/email. Either way, your server error logs may contain more information that would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, the problem is in the contact form code. Does this code work out of the box? Or Do I have to code how the contact form is processed with a default mezzanine install?

Comment: I can help with Djrill, but don't know anything about Mezzanine, sorry. I'd suggest editing your question (and tags) to make it clear you're now asking about errors in Mezzanine contact forms, which may attract people here who know Mezzanine. (Might be helpful to check the "related" questions once you update, too.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I had my app installed on a Linode VPS running Debian. I did not have postfix setup and configured to act as a relay. Once I did this by following:

https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/postfix-smtp-debian7

everything worked